# ProjectEuler' 8: solution works for example but can't find answer

Tags: c

I am learning C and trying to improve my skills solving Project Euler exercises. I am stuck with [problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

This is my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdin
  #define ADJ_GRAB 4

  uint64_t max_prod;

  //Takes a char array and returns converted int array
  int *arr_atoi(const char nos[]){

   static int c_ints[ADJ_GRAB];
   int nos_len = strlen(nos);

   int z;
   for (z = 0; z < nos_len; z++)
    c_ints[z] = nos[z] - '0';

   return c_ints;
  }

  //Returns the sum of the adjacent digits
  void check_sum(const char nos[]){

      extern uint64_t max_prod;
      uint64_t c_prod = 1;
      int *tc_ints = arr_atoi(nos);

      int z;
      for (z = 0; z < ADJ_GRAB; z++)
          c_prod *= *(tc_ints + z);

      max_prod = c_prod > max_prod ? c_prod : max_prod;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      //define the number list, its length and a buffer to hold adjacent digits.
    char *no_list =
       "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
       "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
       "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
       "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
       "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
       "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
       "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
       "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
       "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
       "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
       "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
       "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
       "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
       "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
       "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
       "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
       "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
       "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
       "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
       "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int list_len = strlen(no_list);
    char tmp_buff[ADJ_GRAB+1];

    //iterate over the number list
    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < list_len; z++){
        //Take ADJ_GRAB adjacent numbers and check their product
        if ((z + ADJ_GRAB) < list_len){
            strncpy_s(tmp_buff, ADJ_GRAB + 1, no_list + z, ADJ_GRAB);
            check_sum(tmp_buff);
        }
      }

      printf("%u\n", max_prod);

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
  }
```

You can change how many adjacent digits you test by modifying ADJ_GRAB. If you run it with four, as in the problem's example, the product is 5832 (which is the correct product) but if you run it with 13, the product is not correct.

Thank you.

Comment: So the likely problem is that you are overflowing a 32 bit integer. Try using `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: @sharth thank you for your anwser. I've just tried using uint64_t but the product I get is still incorrect.

Comment: Could you edit your code to the version that you have that uses `uint64_t`? It's possible that you missed a spot.

Comment: @sharth the solution is 40824 so there is no way for this issue to be related to integer overflow.

Comment: The product of the first 13 numbers is `5000940`, which is greater than your suggested solution.

Comment: Additionally, from just scanning the problem space, `9*7*5*3*6*9*7*8*1*7*9*7*7` doesn't fit in an int.

Comment: @sharth You are right, I'm sorry. Edited. Now I get 2039787520 which still isn't the correct anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1: The number of bits

Your solution suffers from integer overflow. You're doing math on an `int`, which is likely a 32 bit number.

From just scanning the problem space, I came across:

```
9*7*5*3*6*9*7*8*1*7*9*7*7 == 8,821,658,160 == 0x2_0DCF_D230
```

Which is a 34 bit (unsigned) number.

### Part 2: Compilers should provide better warnings

```
blue.cc:34:33: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        printf("%u\n", max_prod);
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~
                %llu
```

You're printf format string doesn't match the argument. You probably want something like `"%llu"`.

Comment: Sir, you are right with both corrections: integer overflow and the format identifier. I changed it to %llu and the printed value now was 23514624000 which **is** the correct answer. Thank you very much.